# C++ getIntArrayAverage

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and am working on an assignment. The function should take the array and the number of items in the array. I am getting errors in my main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double getIntArrayAverage(int *array, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        sum += array[x];
    }
    double average = (sum / size);
    return average;
}
int main(void)
{
    int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int size = 10;
    double avg = getIntArrayAverage(*array, size);
    printf("%f", avg);
}
```

Comment: If an answer solved your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies here.

```
double avg = getIntArrayAverage(*array, size);
```

`getIntArrayAverage()` function accepts the address of the array and you've provided the 0th element of the array.

The correct way to pass the array i.e. address of the 0th element is to call the function like the following.

```
double avg = getIntArrayAverage(array, size);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to remove the '*' from in front of array.

array decays to an int pointer, there is no need to dereference it.

```
double avg = getIntArrayAverage(array, size);
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors should be type errors and they are correct.

- The first parameter of `getIntArrayAverage` has to be an `int*`!
- `array` in your main is of type `int[10]` but decays to `int*` when passed as argument.
- `*array` on the other hand is of type `int`. It is the first element of the `array`.

So the correct line would be:

```
double avg = getIntArrayAverage(array, size);
```